# DLT message consumption

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using Spring kafka 2.7 non blocking retry mechanism. During the Spring Kafka Retry Mechanism, the kafka listenser consumes the messages from main topic, retry topic and DLT Topic,
We want the listener to consume from main and retry topic only.

Is there a easy way to do the setup?

As we dont want the same consumer to process the DLT messages. The DLT would also be consumed by another process, to send notification for requests.

```
// our configuration

 @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory
        = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
  }


@Bean
  public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {

    List<Class<? extends Throwable>> throwableList = Arrays.asList(IllegalArgumentException.class,
        IllegalAccessException.class);

    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
        .newInstance()
        .dltHandlerMethod(XYZ.class, "xyz")
        .exponentialBackoff(delayMs, backoffMultiplier, maxIntervalInMs)
        .maxAttempts(retryAttempt)
        .notRetryOn(throwableList)
        .doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()
        .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory())
        .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
        .create(template);
  }
```

Comment: @GaryRussell : Please help on the same

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `.dltHandlerMethod(XYZ.class, "xyz")`.

**EDIT**

This will still create a default DLT handler which will just log the record.

You can either use a different group in the "other" consumer, or you can manually start the containers (except the DLT container).

Set `autoStartup="false"` on the `@KafkaListener`; then add this...

```java
@Bean
ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    return args -> {
        registry.getListenerContainerIds().forEach(id -> {
            if (!id.endsWith("-dlt")) {
                registry.getListenerContainer(id).start();
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary for your reply. If we remove the above method, the default DLT handler method will be called results moving the offset. We want to configure the dlt, but it shouldn't be consumed by us and spring default dlt logger. We want to listen to dlt topics with the same group in another specific listener is our requirement.

Comment: It's not currently possible to do that - you can either use a differnt group for the other consumer, or see the edit for another work around.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/4e2a23799641d58905d3f5aa2190f320da980d5c - this will be available in 2.8 (due next month).